# Extjs 4.2 Sortable grid with fixed position for one record

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a simple grid with sorting on. I want to allow users to sort by any column, but at the same time I want one record to always display at last position (that record is recognized by ID). Is there a way to do this?

I'm using ExtJS 4.2.2.

Comment: What is the purpose of that record, a summary? If so, there's a plugin for summaries.

Comment: No, it's not a summary. It's an empty record that user can edit, then it becomes normal record and a new, empty one is added.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't keep a blank record for editing in the grid all the time. What I usually do is to provide the user a means to add record when he needs, let him to edit and save it.

You may have different requirements, anyway, you can see how this logic works here: [Editable and Writable ExtJS Grid Example](http://extjs.eu/ext-examples/#writable-grid)

This approach saves you from solving the sorting problem.

Comment: While I do think a button is a better solution, I'm not the one who makes decisions :) I like your solution, though.